# Regex code for TeamSpeak3 ControlBot plugin

Tags: regex, teamspeak

I want a code that doesn't kick `Name_Surname` but kicks anything else. My current code is :

```
^(?![A-Z][a-z]+(?:_[A-Z][a-z]+)*).*$
```

I need one more rule to add to this code.

I want to allow `[C]Name_Surname` format too.

This C letter can change for max 3 letters long for example `[CAD]Name_Surname` but not allow *[CADS]Name_Surname*

https://regex101.com/r/pbz4LP/1

Simply I want to allow match4 match5 and match6 from this link but not allow match7

Answer (score 0):

Just modify a bit your actual regex into:

```
^(?!\[[A-Z]{1,3}\].*$)(?![A-Z][a-z]+(?:_[A-Z][a-z]+)+$).*
```

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/vL8sKT/1)

Comment: Tnx toto it works
Can you add the match4 allowed as Name_Surname i mean to allow this Name_Surname-Name or match4 on zour link 
Tnx a lot

Comment: @Enis: Just modify the last part: `(?:[-_][A-Z][a-z]+)`